# Passing an object to a thread in rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, dependency-injection

I'm used to writing code in python and C++ and try to get along with rust. I want to pass an object to a thread and call a method of this object.
In addition, the object is passed to the thread by dependency injection because I aim to reuse this module.
When the function expects the Object `FIFO`, everything's fine. But when using the trait, it fails.

I get the following error when passing the clone of the object to the thread:

> borrowed data escapes outside of function
> requirement occurs because of the type `Mutex<&dyn testTrait>`, which makes the generic argument `&dyn testTrait` invariant
> the struct `Mutex<T>` is invariant over the parameter `T`

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

pub trait testTrait: Send + Sync {
    fn test(&self, i: i32) -> i32;
}

pub struct FIFO {}

unsafe impl Send for FIFO {}
unsafe impl Sync for FIFO {}

impl testTrait for FIFO {
    fn test(&self, i: i32) -> i32 {
        return i;
    }
}

impl FIFO {}

fn main() {
    let fifo = FIFO {};
    caller(&fifo);
}

pub fn caller(t: &dyn testTrait) {
    let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(t));
    let clone = a.clone();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        if let Ok(mut x) = clone.lock() {
            x.test(5);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You make a Mutex around a reference, but that doesn't extend the lifetime of the reference. The thread can still outlive the reference since the thread can outlive the function body. You'll either need to change it to a `Box<dyn testTrait>` parameter or use [`std::thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html)

Comment: `unsafe impl Send for FIFO` is a bad sign. That should not be necessary. Those are derived automatically *if* your `struct` is fine. If it isn't, don't just make Rust assume it is. Don't bust out `unsafe` to solve problems. You can probably go your whole career without *needing* to do that if you do things the Rust way.

Comment: Tip: Pass in `Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn X>>` if you want read-write access, or just `Box<dyn X>` if it's strictly read-only.

Comment: @PitaJ You mean the `Arc`.

Comment: @tadman Those `unsafe impl`s are also completely unecessary (the code wotks without them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a reference in this situation is probably the wrong choice, because a reference connects the lifetime of the thread with the calling function.

This problem is not specific to Rust, Rust just complains about it because Rust has a zero-undefined-behavior tolerance.

In C++, for example, it is undefined behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

struct TestTrait {
  virtual int test() = 0;
};

struct Foo : TestTrait {
  int value;
  int test() override { return value; }
};

int main() {
  {
    Foo x;
    x.value = 10;

    std::thread thrd([&x]() {
      std::cout << x.test() << std::endl;
    });
    thrd.detach();
  }

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

  return 0;
}
```

```
Segmentation fault
```

So as @PitaJ already points out, there are two solutions:

- Make sure the thread doesn't outlive the `main` function by using [`std::thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html)
- Make the data reference counted via `Arc`

I assume you want to go the `Arc` route because you already started with that.
You can't place the reference in the `Arc`, though, you have to put the object itself into the `Arc`. The whole point of an `Arc` is to have multiple ownership, and for that, the `Arc` has to actually own the object, not borrow it.

Here is a possible solution with `Arc`:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

pub trait TestTrait: Send + Sync {
    fn test(&mut self, i: i32) -> i32;
}

pub struct FIFO {}

impl TestTrait for FIFO {
    fn test(&mut self, i: i32) -> i32 {
        return i;
    }
}

impl FIFO {}

fn main() {
    let fifo = Arc::new(Mutex::new(FIFO {}));
    caller(Arc::clone(&fifo));
    std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
}

pub fn caller(t: Arc<Mutex<impl TestTrait + 'static>>) {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        if let Ok(mut x) = t.lock() {
            println!("{}", x.test(5));
        }
    });
}
```

```
5
```

Note that:

- You need to use `impl` instead of `dyn` as this situation is too complex for trait objects
- No need to use `unsafe` anywhere; in fact, you should never define `Send` and `Sync` manually, as they are derived automatically